# Remove Text from below of the BarCode Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, barcode

How can I remove text from below of Barcode generated with Zxing (Vb.net)

Generate Barcode:

```
Sub Barcode()
        Dim writer As New BarcodeWriter
        writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
        PictureBox1.Image = writer.Write(Fullcode.Text)
    End Sub
```

Add to print:

```
Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(New Point(10, 300), PictureBox1.Size)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, rect)
```

The print Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: IIRC, `[EncodingOptions].PureBarcode = true`

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved my problem...